# Tricky exercise on sufficient statistics (undergraduate level)

Tags: probability, statistics, sufficient-statistics

During my semester, my class and I were subjected to an interesting exercise that challenged my entire understanding of sufficient statistics (It turns out that the median of this exercise was 0). Here the exercise

[image]

But even with the correction that was given, I still don't understand. The first question defines exactly $T_1(Y)$ as the MAP rule, doesn't it? I don't understand how it can't be a sufficient statistic.

Can someone help me ? Thanks !

Comment: Intuitively, observing $Y=-1$ would make $H=1$ more likely than observing $Y=-2$ would.  But $T_1(-1)=T_1(-2)$ and fails to convey this difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition:
Let $X_1, ... ,X_n$ be a random sample from the distribution $p_X(x;\theta )$. A statistic $S = f(X_1 ... , X_n)$ is defined to be a **sufficient** statistic if and only if the conditional distribution of $X_1, ... ,X_n$ given $S = s$ does not depend on $\theta$ for any value $s$ of $S$.

In other words: given $S$,  $(X_1, ... ,X_n)$ contains no additional information about $\theta$.

---

Transcribing to our current problem: we sample $Y$ from the distribution $p_{Y}(y; h)$. A statistic $T=f(Y)$ is sufficient iff $p_{Y|T}(y;t)$ does not depend on $h$ for any value $t$ of $T$.

Note that $T_1 = -1$ if $y=-1$ or $y=-2$.

If $h=-1$:
$$ p_{Y|T_1}(-1;-1) = \frac{0.3}{0.6} = \frac{1}{2} $$

However, if $h=1$:
$$ p_{Y|T_1}(-1;-1) = \frac{0.21}{0.4} \neq \frac{1}{2} $$

Thus, $p_{Y|T_1}(y;t)$ depends on the value of $h$.

In other words: given $T_1$, $Y$ still has additional information about $h$.